# Apache Spark structured streaming with Kinesis stops processing records after first batch

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use Spark Structured Streaming (via AWS Glue) to process a Kinesis stream every 6 hours and partition the data to CSV files. The script appears to work, but only ever processes the first 20,000 records, never progressing beyond this, regardless of how many times it is invoked.

The pyspark script is:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_format

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("archive").getOrCreate()

schema = "<valid avro schema>"

df = spark.readStream. \
    format("kinesis"). \
    option("streamName", "STREAM_NAME"). \
    option("region", "AWS_REGION"). \
    option("endpointUrl", "KINESIS_ENDPOINT"). \
    option("startingPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON"). \
    option("awsAccessKeyId", "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"). \
    option("awsSecretKey", "AWS_SECRET_KEY"). \
    load()

parsed_data = df.select(from_avro("data", schema).alias("data"))

parsed_data = parsed_data \
    .withColumn("year", date_format(col("start_time"), "yyyy")) \
    .withColumn("month", date_format(col("start_time"), "MM")) \
    .withColumn("day", date_format(col("start_time"), "dd"))

q = parsed_data.writeStream. \
    outputMode("append"). \
    format("csv"). \
    option("path", "tmp/archive/output/"). \
    option("checkpointLocation", "tmp/archive/output_checkpoint/"). \
    partitionBy("location_id", "year", "month", "day"). \
    trigger(availableNow=True). \
    start()

q.awaitTermination()
```

After first run, the `tmp/archive/output` directory is filled with exactly 20,000 CSV records, partitioned correctly by `location_id/year/month/day`.

The problem is that the CSV files span only ~10 minutes, while there is ~9 hours' worth in Kinesis. Based on my interpretation of the `availableNow` [trigger mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers), Spark should process **all** data that is available at the time of invocation, but it instead just seems to be processing a single (micro?) batch.

Furthermore, successive invocations of `spark-submit` do not result in any more data being processed; relevant log output is below:

```
23/12/20 18:45:12 INFO KinesisSource: This is the first batch. Returning Empty sequence
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO KinesisReader: List shards in Kinesis Stream:  Buffer({ShardId: shardId-000000000000,HashKeyRange: {StartingHashKey: 0,EndingHashKey: 340282366920938463463374607431768211455},SequenceNumberRange: {StartingSequenceNumber: 49647532512655086954158498396575396624819731014015254530,}})
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO KinesisSource: End Offset is {"metadata":{"streamName":"STREAM_NAME","batchId":"0"},"shardId-000000000000":{"iteratorType":"TRIM_HORIZON","iteratorPosition":""}}
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO KinesisSource: Processing 1 shards from List(ShardInfo(shardId-000000000000,TRIM_HORIZON,))
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO KinesisSource: GetBatch generating RDD of offset range: ShardInfo(shardId-000000000000,TRIM_HORIZON,)
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Resuming at batch 1 with committed offsets {KinesisSource[STREAM_NAME]: {"metadata":{"streamName":"STREAM_NAME","batchId":"0"},"shardId-000000000000":{"iteratorType":"TRIM_HORIZON","iteratorPosition":""}}} and available offsets {KinesisSource[STREAM_NAME]: {"metadata":{"streamName":"STREAM_NAME","batchId":"0"},"shardId-000000000000":{"iteratorType":"TRIM_HORIZON","iteratorPosition":""}}}
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {KinesisSource[STREAM_NAME]: {"metadata":{"streamName":"STREAM_NAME","batchId":"0"},"shardId-000000000000":{"iteratorType":"TRIM_HORIZON","iteratorPosition":""}}}
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "b04f346a-c7d0-4ff3-9520-e2816b225e96",
  "runId" : "e538b1f8-0d93-4a90-b8f0-0271a3d2bff5",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2023-12-20T18:45:13.536Z",
  "batchId" : 1,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "latestOffset" : 7,
    "triggerExecution" : 124
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KinesisSource[STREAM_NAME]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "metadata" : {
        "streamName" : "STREAM_NAME",
        "batchId" : "0"
      },
      "shardId-000000000000" : {
        "iteratorType" : "TRIM_HORIZON",
        "iteratorPosition" : ""
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "metadata" : {
        "streamName" : "STREAM_NAME",
        "batchId" : "0"
      },
      "shardId-000000000000" : {
        "iteratorType" : "TRIM_HORIZON",
        "iteratorPosition" : ""
      }
    },
    "latestOffset" : {
      "metadata" : {
        "streamName" : "STREAM_NAME",
        "batchId" : "1"
      },
      "shardId-000000000000" : {
        "iteratorType" : "AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER",
        "iteratorPosition" : "49647532512655086954158498435270694259044830772436402178"
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "FileSink[tmp/archive/output/]",
    "numOutputRows" : -1
  }
}
23/12/20 18:45:13 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Finished processing all available data for the trigger, terminating this Trigger.AvailableNow query
```

The contents of `tmp/archive/output_checkpoint/sources/0/shard-commit/0/shardId-000000000000` is:

```json
{"shardId":"shardId-000000000000","iteratorType":"AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER","iteratorPosition":"49647532512655086954158498435270694259044830772436402178"}
```

(this iterator position appears to be correct - requesting the next records via the AWS console yields timestamps close to the latest that are saved to the CSV files).

My development environment is a local installation of the `aws-glue-libs` Docker image (version `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01`) since I ultimately intend to deploy this script to AWS Glue. The script/checkpoint/output directories exist on the host and mounted as a Docker volume.